# Why is Android looking for QVGA resources in the wrong order mdpi > hdpi > ldpi?

Tags: android, resources, resolution

I'm trying to do some testing with a QVGA emulator and I find that it looks for an image resource in the mentioned order.

drawable-mdpi 1st
drawable-hdpi 2nd
drawable-ldpi 3rd
(it does get found only after I change the name of the image in the other two dirs for testing)

I would expect it to be ldpi first.

When running other emulators (HVGA and WVGA) they use their appropriate drawable dirs... it's only QVGA. The only code that I see could affect this is here (based on the docs)

I have tested this with a 2.0 emulator and a 1.6, I get the same result.

Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I have to enter the density manually.

If I just select QVGA as a Skin from the "Built-in" drop down list it puts 120 as the value for the Abstracted LCD density, but it doesnt seem to work...

So I delete that property and add it back, then change the value to 120. Thank you much Dave for your direction.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `hw.lcd.density` setting in the `config.ini` for you QVGA AVD.  If this is set incorrectly then the emulator might not be running as a low density device.  It should be 120.

You can also check using the **Details** button in the **Android SDK and AVD Manager** GUI which you can launch from Eclipse or by entering `android` at a command prompt:

[image]

Comment: Wow, really good thought, but both of the emulators im using have 120